# How to set and print Java Script variable value using HTML and React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Apologies, I'm a complete novice when it comes to web development. I'm using a bit of React, HTML and JavaScript.

I have this line of code (some of which was given to me) which basically sets the state of an item in a list to either 'selected' or 'notSelected'.

`{items.map((paymentCat) => { return <PaymentlistItem key={paymentCat.id}   paymentCat{paymentCat} state={paymentCat.id === selectedCat ? 'selected' : 'notSelected'} onClick={() => { updateSelectedCat(paymentCat.id) }}/>})}`

The problem I'm having is, when a button is clicked which triggers the onClick function and updates the state, I'd like to output the values of the selected item elsewhere in my HTML e.g.

I'd like to do something like:

`<script> document.getElementById('elementIdText').innerHTML = {paymentCat.id} </script>`

I'm having problems with this though - the above script works if I hard code some value but not when I want to access the selected paymentCat.id value.

E.g. this works:

`<script> document.getElementById('elementIdText').innerHTML = 'some random text' </script>`

I have also tried the following but it doesn't work either:

`var selectedId; var selectedCat; var selectedPrice;`

`    {items.map((paymentCat) => { return <PaymentlistItem key={paymentCat.id} paymentCat=. {paymentCat} state={paymentCat.id === selectedCat ? 'selected' : 'notSelected'} onClick={() => { updateSelectedCat(paymentCat.id); selectedId = paymentCat.id; selectedCat =  paymentCat.category; selectedPrice = paymentCat.price }}/>})}

```
<script>
document.getElementById('paymentText').innerHTML = {selectedId}
</script>`
```

---

Would really appreciate some help and a simple solution to the above as I'm new to this and have to use existing HTML structure.

As per my question, tried outputting values from the objects which have their state set onClick and also setting local variables but I can't get it to work.

Comment: When you choose a "tool" to build an app, you should lean towards what that tool offers to implement a business logic.

Comment: Please clarify and update your question title as "print" means something entirely different than setting a value in an HTML element text which is what you appear to want.  Doing the latter with Javascript is a trivial basic task but we may not know all we need to about your desire. FWIW  you indicate you are less experience - perhaps start with basic HTML/Javascript before layering on reactjs here?

Comment: If you are working in React, **do not** directly modify the DOM using things like `.innerHTML = ...` As mentioned above, a good understanding of the underlying technologies is pretty much essential before jumping into React.

Answer (score 0):

React is a UI library. It works by updating the UI from changes in state. It has its own method for reconciling DOM changes in response to those state changes. So you shouldn't be using native DOM methods like `getElementById` at all because it will conflict with how React works.

(Note also that the code you've been given has at least one syntax error in it which will crash your app - `paymentCat{paymentCat}`: there should be an equals sign in there).

Here's an example using a little of your code which displays some simple items. When a button is clicked the `handleClick` handler is called which updates the state with the `id`.

When the state changes the component is re-rendered. This means that the value of `selected={item.id === selectedCat}` will change which means that the class of the button will *also* change.

It also means that the text output of the `id` which is what is in state and is initially set as `null` will now show (it's no longer `null` - it's the value of the selected button).

If you're unsure of how React works [there's extensive documentation](https://react.dev/learn) that you could look at.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Pass in the mock items to the component
function Example({ items }) {

  // Initialise the state to `null`
  const [ selectedCat, setSelectedCat ] = useState(null);

  // The handler to update the state with an id
  function updateSelectedCat(id) {
    setSelectedCat(id);
  }

  // Iterate over the items, and create some
  // PaymentlistItem components. The second part of this code
  // displays the value of the state when the state is not `null`
  return (
    <main>
      {items.map(item => {
        return (
          <PaymentlistItem
            key={item.id}
            data={item}
            selected={item.id === selectedCat}
            handleClick={updateSelectedCat}
          />
        )
      })}
      {selectedCat ? (
        <div className="output">
          Selected ID: {selectedCat}
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </main>
  );

}

// Creates some buttons
function PaymentlistItem({ data, selected, handleClick }) {
  
  // A joined array of classes used on the button
  const cn = ['button', selected && 'selected'].join(' ');
  
  return (
    <section className="item">
      <button
        className={cn}
        type="button"
        onClick={() => handleClick(data.id)}
      >{data.id}: {data.name}
      </button>
    </section>
  );

}

// Mock items passed into the Example component
const items = [{ id: 1, name: 'bob' }, { id: 2, name: 'dave' }];

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example items={items} />);
```

```css
.item ~ .item { margin-top: 1rem; }
button { font-size: 1.2rem; width: 200px; padding: 0.25rem; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.selected { background-color: lightgreen; }
.output { margin-top: 2rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```